# Changing content of a website without using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

My client wants to update content in a website such aa "business opening hours" or other details of their business.

I was wondering whether there is a way to have them update the content without having sql entries for each of the fields and then providing a form for them to update.

Some of this info is hardcoded in a php page per language, as there is a routing script that will choose the corresponding page to pull info from depending on the chosen language.

Example of current info display:

```
$openingHours = "Our business opens from 9am to 3pm and then evenings from 6pm to 10pm";
$introText = "Welcome to ABCD, where we offer the greatest food in town";
```

The best would be to enable my client to update the php file but in a user friendly mode, not manual edit. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use config.php to make that and on it you can use like above:

```
<?php

$business = array();

$business['opening'] = 9;
$business['closing'] = 21;

?>
```

and you can include it and use on whereever u want. (Or u can make that config file via ini. But php is easier)

Comment: But, how could my client change for example Opening from 9 to 8.30? Could he alter the config.php without manually editing the file?

Comment: You can write the array outputs on panel like that : 

`<?php

require "config.pnp"

$opening = $business['opening'];

?>

<input type="text" name="opening" value="<?php echo $opening;?>"/>`

via inputs from admin create an text like config.php and file_put_contents to older. Not want to try that u can use mongo or any noSql